# How to fix the error `unrecognized option '--color never'`?

Tags: manjaro, pacman, aur

I was looking to try [suplemon](https://github.com/richrd/suplemon), so I run

```
pacaur -S suplemon
```

and face the following error:

```
/usr/bin/pacman: unrecognized option '--color never'
```

This error blocks the installation. How can I fix it?

Comment: Unmaintained software is broken by pacman update. Quelle surprise.

Comment: @jasonwryan I am looking for another (coming from yaourt (yes I know)). [well](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers)

Answer (score -1):

First, it could be a [known bug](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/pacman-dev/2018-June/022561.html), so be sure to update everything. Then, check if the option Color is commented. Open `/etc/pacman.conf` and if you have:

```
# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
# We cannot check disk space from within a chroot environment
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists
```

replace it with:

```
# Misc options
#UseSyslog
Color
#TotalDownload
# We cannot check disk space from within a chroot environment
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists
```

As far as I can tell, this fixed it for me. I believe this kept pacaur from sending color=never.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/8o5ol0/error_using_pacman_usrbinpacman_unrecognized/)

Comment: This isn't a fix. AUR helpers that wrap pacman should be able to use `pacman.conf` options. The issue is that pacaur is unmaintained and has as a result fallen behind pacman development.

Comment: Ad the end it worked for me. I am looking to switch though.